# Pylab doesn't "draw" bars with height of 0

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to draw a bar chart with the following code:

```
import pylab as p
first = ["2013-02-05", "2013-02-12", "2013-02-19", "2013-02-26", "2013-03-05", "2013-03-12"]

second = [0, 0, 0, 25, 35, 0]

fig = p.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
N = len(second)
ind = range(N)
ax.bar(ind, second, facecolor='#777777', align='center', ecolor='black')
ax.set_xticklabels(first)
fig.autofmt_xdate()
```

The result is here (sorry, can't post images yet): http://oi48.tinypic.com/vzxah3.jpg

As you can see, the bars with the value of 0 are omitted. I want just free space there.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about change 0 to 0.0001 by `numpy.clip()`?

```
import pylab as p
first = ["", "2013-02-05", "2013-02-12", "2013-02-19", "2013-02-26", "2013-03-05", "2013-03-12"]

second = [0.0, 0.0, 0, 25, 35, 0]

fig = p.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
N = len(second)
ind = range(1, N+1)
ax.bar(ind, np.clip(second, 0.001, np.inf), facecolor='#777777', align='center', ecolor='black', )
ax.set_xticklabels(first)
fig.autofmt_xdate()
```

[image]